# Java heap out of memory exception tomcat linux

Tags: linux, apache, jakarta-ee, server, tomcat7

[image]

Please help me,my live application sometimes throw exception out of memory java heap 
however I set the max size to 512M half of virtual server size 
I've searched on google and traced my Server like attached image 
can anyone tell me where is the error please ?

the data in console is below

```
  System load:  0.01               Processes:           74
  Usage of /:   16.2% of 29.40GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 60%              
  Swap usage:   0%


developer@pc:/$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           994        754        239          0         24        138
-/+ buffers/cache:        592        401
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Comment: Please include the text instead of screenshot of notepad.

Comment: It's a screenshot of console , done I've written the data as text